# return promise after multiple then is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

i have a method that calls a service that performs a axios get request. This returns a promise.I then call .then and return the response. when i call loadData i get a promise returned.

```
loadData(){
      return myService.getData().then(response=>{              
            //do some stuff
                return response;                  
        })
   }
```

when i call

```
Promise.all([loadData()]).then(function([data]){
  console.log([data])
}
```

the `console.log` shows my data that i have loaded via the service.

if i change my loadData method to the following - then after the `Promise.all` logs to the console i get undefined.

```
loadData(){
      return myService.getData().then(response=>{              
            //do some stuff                                      
        }).then(res =>{
            //do more stuff
            return res;
        }
   }
```

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong;

Comment: I'm curious what the purpose of `Promise.all([loadData()])` is? You only have a single promise there, so `Promise.all` seems unnecessary.

Comment: ive got other promises that will be added into that - i left them out in the example as i felt wasnt necessary to solve my issue.

Comment: Pretty much what I figured. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of a fulfillment handler is the input to (or promise of input to) the next fulfillment handler. From your description, you're not returning anything where you have `//do some stuff`:

```
loadData(){
    return myService.getData().then(response=>{              
        //do some stuff
        return /*something appropriate*/;     // <=========================== 
    }).then(res =>{                           // <=== it will come through here
        //do more stuff
        return res;
    }); // <========== Added missing ); here
}
```

Calling a function that doesn't return anything results in `undefined`, so that's why `res` is `undefined`.

Side note: You don't need two fulfillment handlers (`then` handlers) unless what you're returning in the first one is a promise (or other thenable).